# Strange Problem with asp.net c# assigning string

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a div element in my html,

```
<div id="userSolution" runat="server" text="1234512345123451234512345"></div>
```

Yes it does contain 25 characters,

i have a button:

```
<asp:Button id="saveGame" runat="server" text="Save Game" onclick="saveGame_Click" />
```

server Code:

```
protected void saveGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string clientInput = userSolution.Attributes["text"];
}
```

So why... when i debug, does `clientInput` = "" ?

By my reckoning... `text="1234512345123451234512345"`

so `string clientInput= userSolution.Attribute["text"];` should work right? :s

confused...

even if the div is:

```
<div id="userSolution" runat="server">1234512345123451234512345</div>
```

and i read

```
string clientId = userSolution.InnerHTML;
```

Still Fails

Comment: No. Div elements have never had a text attribute.

Comment: Even if i read it from innerHTML and make my text value part of divs innerhtml... still fails

Comment: Inner Text Doesnt work either... Its annoying because after i've stepped over the line to realise client input = "", if i go onto inspect element using chrome, i can see that the div still holds the value... before and after the server side event handler is called!

Comment: Did you use InnerText AND move the "12345.." between the <div> and </div> tags? There is no "text" attribute for a div. Doing both of those will work.

Edit: I wrote that before I saw your last edit which says you did try that. Researching further...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't post back the data that way in a div tag *if you are setting the value of the div on the client side*. You'll need to use a form element, like a hidden textbox if you want to use a straight ASP.NET postback.

Here's a simple example. It uses a javascript event to set the text of a HiddenField when the button is pressed and then displays the text on postback.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function copyToHiddenField() {
        var hidden = document.getElementById("<%= txtHidden.ClientID %>");
        var theDivText = document.getElementById("thedata").innerHTML;
        hidden.value = theDivText;
        return true;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="thedata">Here's the data!</div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="txtHidden" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSumbit" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSumbit_OnClick" runat="server" />
        <asp:Literal ID="litText" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSumbit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return copyToHiddenField();");
}

public void btnSumbit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    litText.Text = txtHidden.Value;
}
</script>
```

**EDIT**
As stated in the answers/comments, you can use the `InnerText` property of a `div` tag when `runat="server"` is specified, but you will only be able read out the `InnerText` that is set when the page is rendered. Client side updates to the `InnerText` of the div will not be sent to the server on postback.

Comment: You CAN do that if you really want to. Maybe the real question is why would the OP want to, and I think that's where you're headed with using a hidden field. If that's what you want though, why not use asp:HiddenField?

Comment: @ashelvey I would either use HiddenField (as in the sample code above) or use AJAX to send back the data. My point was just that since div isn't a form element, any data that is contained in the div isn't going to be a part of the POST request the browser makes when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: Right. It will be in ASP.NET state though, so it is *possible*, but it's definitely not the right way to do it as you've stated. I guess I'm just being pedantic. :) I agree with your approach, voting up.

Comment: Very well explained. Works Perfectly:) Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Try InnerText, and also change

```
<div id="userSolution" runat="server" text="1234512345123451234512345"></div>
```

to

```
<div id="userSolution" runat="server">1234512345123451234512345</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the asp:panel. That should give you what you're after (a div in client and .Text in server code

**Edit**

Wow, it's been a while and I actually thought there was a Text property - I even checked old projects in disbelief!! :-/

Comment: i used asp:panel Before i used div... and after asp:panel Failed i moved to divs... and now divs fail :'(

Comment: Panel does NOT have a property Text.